# Object to object mapping using Automapper causing exception

Tags: c#, wpf, automapper

I am trying to map viewModel class to Model.

Here is ViewModel

```
...
public class LicenseInfoViewModel
{
   public SystemInfo SystemInfo { get; set; }
}
...
```

Here is my Model

```
...
public class LicenseInfoModel
{
   public SystemInfo SystemInfo { get; set; }
}
...
```

[image]
Here is the exception I am getting while mapping classes, as

```
SystemInfo
```

is a class in common code(separate project)

and here is the exception I am getting
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with load a separate assembly `Proofix.Utility` not with AutoMapper.

If this already marked, so you should look through referenced assemblies 
*from* `Proofix.Utility` and mark them with `CopyLocal="True"`

I guess, that marking this assembly in the references with `CopyLocal="true"` will solve the problem.

`CopyLocal="True"` actually means that during the build `*.dll` file of referenced assembly will be stored in the `bin` directory of startup project.

If it will not work check Configuration Manager (Build/Configuration Manager...) for checked checkbox `Build` for `Proofix.Utility` project.

If it will not work - try to Clean/Rebuild the solution or re-open solution in the Visual Studio.

Comment: well, try Clean and Rebuild the solution or restart the Visual Studio - this will force solution to reload

Comment: the last suggestion is to check Configuration Manager (Build/Configuration Manager...) that there is checked checkbox `Build` for Proofix.Utility in the current active solution platform, or try to change active solution platform to Any CPU or x86 or x64.
and the kind of stupid way - to check the presence of `Proofix.Utility.dll` in application `bin` folder, if there is no - add it here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to map with this code if you think their is an issue in mapping code

```
   public static P MapObject<T, P>(T from, P to)
        {
            var p = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (P));
            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in typeof(T).GetProperties())
            {
                typeof(P)
                    .GetProperty( propertyInfo.Name,
                        BindingFlags.IgnoreCase |
                        BindingFlags.Instance |
                        BindingFlags.Public)
                    .SetValue(to,
                        propertyInfo.GetValue(from));
            }
            return to;
        }
```